Blender won't launch after install on my child's new pc, please advise
My son installed Blender, He's 11 and I'm not so techy so bear with me!
Blender won't open: just flashes a grey screen.
I went through this forum and tried some things others had suggested (clearing old Blender files, reinstalling, installing older Blender versions, turning off antivirus).
My brother tried troubleshooting over the phone with me. We made sure permissions were on for the program files. I ran the glitch file from within the Blender folder: it gives the error log 'Exception Access Violation' and lots of other potentially useful info I don't understand.
Not sure what else I can try at this stage. I had Blender on my old all in one pc and it was great.

Hi, either discord or https://blenderartists.org/ will be a better place for a back-and-forth conversation, as Blender Stack Exchange has an encyclopedia format not designed for such troubleshooting.

Hello, first never turn off your antivirus when installing software UNLESS you know what you are doing. You should look up the minimum requirement https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ and update the graphic card drivers.

Bugs and crashes are off-topic here. Make sure the PC meets minimum requirements, if it doesn't you could try previous versions, if the PC is new, chances are it does. Try updating GPU drivers - out of date drivers is absolutely the most common cause of problems with running Blender.

As an aside to set expectations, 3d modeling programs can be extremely challenging to learn, depending on your goal.  Their interfaces and workflows are onerous and have a steep learning curve.

@james_t, nothing to worry about. Age doesn't matter here. I know for sure, because I started when I was 12 or 13(Maya, Blender wasn't very good then). It was awesome. It can be a really cool hobby.

Thank you. I'll try those things.
